# Click on the image to slide in and out?

Tags: angularjs, html, css

When I click on the bottom-coupon class, the picture is slowly hidden from right to left, the coupon-layer slides out from left to right. When click closeCoupon, the coupon-layer is hidden from right to left, and the bottom-coupon slides out. Currently I am only Implement show and hide, but no sliding effects，I want to achieve a sliding effect,how to do?

[image: When I click on the image, I want the image to slowly hide from right to left, then remove a mask layer from left to right.]
[image]

```
.bottom-coupon{
  background: url('../images/public/bottom-coupon.png') no-repeat bottom;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 1%;
  z-index: 12;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.coupon-layer{
  background-color:#263646;background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);height: 175px;width: 100%; position: fixed;bottom: 0%; z-index: 12;
  .coupon-layer-pic{
    width: 980px;height:178px;margin: auto;position: relative;
    .coupon-combo{
      position: absolute;
      top: 15%;
      left: 0;
    }
    bottom-coupon-pic{
      transition: all linear 0.5s;
      height:294px;
      width: 121px;
    }
    .ng-hide {
      width: 0;
    }
    .coupon-close{
      background: url('../svg/close-gray.svg') no-repeat bottom;
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      right: 0px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
}

   .controller("footLayerCtrl",["$scope","$rootScope","$filter","factoryGlobal","mTranslate", function($scope,$rootScope,$filter,factoryGlobal,mTranslate) {
        $scope.isShowCoupon=true;
        $scope.isShowLayer=false;
        $scope.showCoupon=function () {
            $scope.isShowCoupon=false;
            $scope.isShowLayer=true;
        }
        $scope.closeCoupon=function () {
            $scope.isShowCoupon=true;
            $scope.isShowLayer=false;
        }
    }])
```

Comment: Please post your html too, preferably in a snippet that reproduces your problem.

Comment: I know，but I don't know why the html code is always not displayed, so I changed to a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you want something like this?

```js
window.onload = ()=>{
  // grab our "button" element that we'll use to hide the coupon
  const btn = document.getElementById('coupon-btn');
  // the coupon div
  const coupon = document.getElementById('special-coupon');
  // attach a click event to our button element
  btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    // if the class is in the element's classList then remove it. Otherwise, add it.
    coupon.classList.toggle('shown');
  });
};
```

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.coupon {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #E51D46;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  transform: translate3d(-550px, 0, 0);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.coupon > .btn {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.btn {
  border: none !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;  
}

.shown {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.shown > .btn {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container coupon shown" id="special-coupon">
  <img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/cancel-close-button-png-9.png" class="btn" id="coupon-btn" />
</div>
```

You can control the speed of the [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) by changing it's duration which is currently set to 0.5s (500ms).

P.S. I used a [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) instead of playing with the `right`, `left` or any similar property since `translate3d` is hardware accelerated (if I remember correctly) and that said advantage would help a lot in performance. On the other hand, you’ll have to leave the button exposed so that you can have the coupon div slide back out again after it’s been hidden.

Also, here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/zyjLRO) :)

Comment: Thank you，the 3D effect provided by CSS3, transform:translate3d(0,0,0) can indeed trigger hardware acceleration, it is very good.

Answer (score -1):

increase and decrease the width of the div on click. that will give you slide in slide out effect.
thanks